# How to compare timestamp with time using pl/sql?

Tags: plsql, timestamp, sql-timestamp

I have parameter :dateSend which has type timestamp and I am trying to make this evaluation.

```
CASE WHEN :dateSend <=  TO_TIMESTAMP('14:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END A
```

It doesn't work. Maybe I should convert :dateSend to time? Like `to_char(CAST(:dateSend AS DATE),'hh24:mi:ss')` but it doesn't work.

I need to show 0 if time from :dateSend is smaller then 14.00.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you want to obtain records having a *time* component which is earlier than 14:00 hours (2pm).  If so, then use this:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN EXTRACT(hour FROM :dateSend) < 14 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS A
FROM yourTable;
```